# Are multi-step examples wanted, in the documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-examples

I've been adding some examples to the Ruby on Rails documentation tag and came across a few topics, which have multiple example, which are connected to each other.

E. g.: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/3606/rails-deployment-capistrano-nginx-passenger-postgresql

Another e. g..: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/3902/configure-angular-with-rails#t=201607280828428093112

This multi-step examples build together a whole tutorial. A tutorial is not an example in my opinion. I've the following ideas to address this 'problem':

- Declare that examples have to be independent and provide moderation tools to flag examples, which doesn't follow this rule.
- If tutorials are wanted in the documentation too, add a new section besides the examples.

Comment: No, examples should obviously not depend on other examples and *certainly* not presuppose a reading order. Examples can be deleted/edited/renamed etc. by people who are not aware of the bigger picture. If they want to write a tutorial, in my opinion it should be one (large) example.

Comment: Agreed this is unwanted. If people want to create a narrative around a set of related code structures then a blog is probably a better tool for the job.

Comment: "A tutorial is not an example in my opinion." Certainly, tutorials should not be shoehorned into the current structure by splitting up over several examples like that. I think a tutorial in a single example (as Gert described) might be okay. I wrote an example that covers a sequence of three steps, and many good examples require that much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, examples should be self-contained and should not depend on the order or content of other examples because:

- The order is not guaranteed
- The content of the other examples can (and will!) change

Readers of Documentation will find it really frustrating if an example refers to a "previous step" that no longer exists.

Comment: Right, though I guess at this early stage of documentation, this is more of a philosophical question, as in: what do we *want* it to do? Not: what are the current technical limitations?

Comment: @Cimbali unfortunately that isn't actually defined yet. :)

Comment: @Cimbali Fair point. I would also argue that examples *should* be self-contained. Small, contained examples are easier to parse and maintain compared to larger, sprawling tutorials.